# Any simple way to clean all Markers, Polylines and other Overlays on Google Maps v3 API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I want to get a new map not using refush the webpage.

thanks

and has easy way to get all Overlays  on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the v2 API, there was the [`clearOverlays()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.clearOverlays) method as [Gaby pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248373/any-simple-way-to-clean-all-markers-polylines-and-other-overlays-on-google-maps/3248426#3248426). However, this method is not present if the v3 API. If I remember correctly, this omission was intentional to keep the library lightweight.

Therefore, with the v3 API, you have to keep a reference of your overlays, and then call `setMap(null)` on each overlay.

Answer (score 1):

FYI for peoples using V3:  From what I have found, V3 does not have a packaged function like V2 does in .clearOverlays();

Here is what I do (as I've gathered from other resources):

```
var gmarkers = []; // establish your markers array;

if (gmarkers) { // plug this in wherever/whenever you want to clear the map of any and all markers;
    for (i in gmarkers) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    gmarkers.length = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the [google map api documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.Methods)

And in particular: [clearOverlays()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.clearOverlays)