# How can I show alternative routes between origin and destination on the map?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

This is the code I use. I produce alternate roots and paint in different colors. But the screen does not work.

Which part is wrong. If you set the response to direction, it draws a single path.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-alonzm?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: When I run your app in stackblitz, I get the error: "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined."

Comment: I do not know the reason for the error, but you can correct the error by deleting ; on line 43.

Comment: Have you tried rendering each route with a separate DirectionsRenderer? Check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909399/display-multiple-routes-on-google-map) out.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I want to show all of the alternate routes generated on the render map at the same time. like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39268344/8404390)